# Phpstorm reverts all work if push rejected

Tags: git, phpstorm

I have a problem, I cant solve. May be someone had similar problem.

I use PhpStorm 7.1 and Git.

When I commit changed files they apper in log and are ready for push. But when I make push and if there is a conflict - PhpStorm **reverts** all changed files! The only way to restore work after that - is to use local changes. It's not supposed to be that way, is it not?

What should I do to make phpStorm not to revert all my work in case of conflicts?

Here is what I see in log:

[image]